# how to chose 2 row of a group whose have the same value in some column and different value in one column?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a col1  index of family , col2 index of persons in each family , col3 mode of travel of each person,  col4 and col5 start and end time of activity how I can choose some row whose in each family, driver and passenger have the same start time and end time?

example:

```
family  persons    mode          start time   end time
   1      1        driver           3            8:45
   1      1        walk             8:45         13:30
   1      1        bus              13:30        15
   1      1        driver           15:00        15:30
   1      2        walk             15:00        15:30
   1      2        driver           22:00        8:30
   1      3        passenger        15:00        15:30
   1      3        walk             8:00         17:00
   1      4        bus              17:00        24:00
   1      4        passenger        15:00        15:30
   1      4        walk             23:00        24:00   
   2      1        driver            8:00         10:00   
   2      1        driver            23:00        24:00   
   2      2        passenger        23:00        24:00
```

In the first family first and second persons are driver ,  third and forth persons are passenger, the start and end time of both passenger is match by first driver (15:00 t0 15:30) so I need to keep 3 rows :( 4,7,10)

second family driver and passenger are matched  also . so the output is:

```
family  persons    mode          start time   end time
   1      1        driver           15:00        15:30
   1      3        passenger        15:00        15:30
   1      4        passenger        15:00        15:30  
   2      1        drive            23:00        24:00   
   2      2        passenger        23:00        24:00
```

Remark: second person in first family has the same start and end time as passenger but her mode is walk and not driver, so we don't need that row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to group by 'family', 'starttime', 'endtime' and `filter` the number of rows greater than 1

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(family, starttime, endtime) %>% 
   filter(n() > 1)
# A tibble: 5 x 5
# Groups:   family, starttime, endtime [2]
#  family persons mode      starttime endtime
#   <int>   <int> <chr>     <chr>     <chr>  
#1      1       1 driver    15:00     15:30  
#2      1       3 passenger 15:00     15:30  
#3      1       4 passenger 15:00     15:30  
#4      2       1 drive     23:00     24:00  
#5      2       2 passenger 23:00     24:00
```

If we need to do this only for selected 'mode', use `%in%` with addditional logical along with the existing one

```
df1 %>% 
     group_by(family, starttime, endtime) %>%
     filter(n() >1,  mode %in% c("driver", "passenger"))
```

---

Or in `base R`, an option is to create logical vector with `duplicated`

```
df1[duplicated(df1[c(1, 4, 5)])|duplicated(df1[c(1, 4, 5)], fromLast = TRUE),]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(family = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), persons = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L), mode = c("driver", "walk", "bus", 
"driver", "driver", "driver", "passenger", "walk", "bus", "passenger", 
"walk", "drive", "drive", "passenger"), starttime = c("3", "8:45", 
"13:30", "15:00", "20:00", "22:00", "15:00", "8:00", "17:00", 
"15:00", "23:00", "8:00", "23:00", "23:00"), endtime = c("8:45", 
"13:30", "15", "15:30", "22:00", "8:30", "15:30", "17:00", "24:00", 
"15:30", "24:00", "10:00", "24:00", "24:00")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```

Comment: how it realize that I need this for driver and passenger mode not for example for walk?

Comment: @sherek_66. Okay, in that case we can do a change in the filter

Comment: yes please, because with duplicate function I get other modes as well

Comment: Hi @sherek_66, if you have the ```dplyr``` package aleady installed, you can just do ```?group-by``` to learn more about that dplyr function. You can also search Stack for ```[group-by] [dplyr]``` and that will show other examples using this function to learn more about it.

Comment: @RussThomas Thanks but my question is more than making a group

Comment: @akrun, tangential question, do you have trick for taking people's data posted as in this question, and getting it into a dataframe so quickly?

Comment: @sherek_66. I updated the answer.  In the example, one of the name is "drive" instead of "driver", typo?